# C FILE reading producing unexpected errors

Tags: c, file, printf

I'm getting back into C and have ran into an error when reading in from Files.  The below code words fine when the file I'm reading is longer then 1 line, but when its one line of text it produces a 2nd line with '>??' characters.  Just wondering what I might be doing wrong here.

I've included the code, the text.txt that its reading and a sample output.

Cheers for any help in advance.

text.txt
"hello this is a sentence"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

FILE * fp;
char * buff;
int i = 0;


fp = fopen("text.txt", "a+");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    perror("exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

//The file read keeps adding ?? to the 2nd line of the file.  I've tried the two pieces of code below
//buff = malloc(size); 
buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

fread(buff, 1, size, fp);

printf("%s\n\n", buff); 

fclose(fp);     


return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

[H[2Jbash-3.2$ ./a.out

hello this is a sentence
v>äˇ

bash-3.2$ q[Kexit
exit

Comment: you may need to increase size of buff by 1 byte to accomodate trailing '\0' char. i am not sure if fread will put it there. so set all bytes of buff to zero to rule out any chances

Comment: @lowtech: `fread` does *not* add a trailing zero, because it is meant to be able to read binary data, not C-strings. Automatically adding a zero byte could be disastrous!

Comment: Why are you using `fread` to "read lines of text"? `fread` will happily include end-of-line characters. Use `fgets` to read *lines*. As a bonus, it *will* zero terminate the string it reads.

Comment: So I should use fread for binary files and fgets for text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

FILE * fp;
char * buff;
int i = 0;


fp = fopen("text.txt", "a+");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    perror("exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

// lowtech: this is the fix of you problem
buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size + 1);
memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(char)*size + 1);

fread(buff, 1, size, fp);

printf("%s\n\n", buff); 

fclose(fp);     


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I knew it wasn't terminating correctly at the NULL but I thought SEEK_SET and SEEK_END would provide it with that information.  Thank you.

Comment: can't replicate the reported problem but agree this is a likely fix

Comment: Why is there so much pointless multiplying by `sizeof(char)` on stackoverflow lately?  And why not kill two birds with one function call:  `buff = calloc(size+1, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to null terminate the string.

Comment: Thank you.  Now to look up memset.